# Quadratic Forms with Positive Discriminant

Tags: number-theory

I have some difficulties on the concept of "Quadratic Forms", I want to explore my knowledge about this topic, but except a few documents I couldn't find much documents, My question is simply about the case when the discriminant is greater than $0$.

In the text-book Harold Davenport's "Multiplicative Number Theory" It has been stated that, in that case each form has infinitely many automorphs and these are determined by the solutions of the Pell's equation given by

$t^2-du^2 = 4 $

I couldn't understand where this comes from, at least could you advise me some notes/documents that explains this case very well, in deeply?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That book of Davenport is not for beginners.

My favorite is *Binary Quadratic Forms* by Duncan Buell http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387970370

the word automorph is a traditional usage that is now somewhat out of favor, but will be found in books by Cassels and Dickson for example. It usually refers to a linear change of variables...

We begin with an indefinite binary form,
$$  f(x,y) = A x^2 + B xy + C y^2, $$
of discriminant $$ d = B^2 - 4 AC. $$

The Gram matrix of the form, in this case let us  the Hessian matrix, is
$$ G =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2A & B \\
B & 2C
\end{array}
\right)
$$

more typing to come

the value of the quadratic form is $(1/2) v^t G v,$ where
$$ v =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Alright, given $t^2 - d u^2 = 4,$ you can confirm this matrix product,

$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{t - Bu}{2} & Au \\
-Cu & \frac{t + Bu}{2}
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2A & B \\
B & 2C
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{t - Bu}{2} & -Cu \\
Au & \frac{t + Bu}{2}
\end{array}
\right) =
$$
$$ 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2A & B \\
B & 2C
\end{array}
\right)
$$

We have $P^t G P = G,$ with
$$ P =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{t - Bu}{2} & -Cu \\
Au & \frac{t + Bu}{2}
\end{array}
\right) =
$$

Since $P^t G P = G$ and $f(v) = (1/2) v^t G v,$ we get infinitely many occurrences of the same value, as
$$   (1/2) (Pv)^t G (Pv) = (1/2) v^t P^t G P v =  (1/2) v^t (P^t G P) v  = (1/2) v^t G v  $$